# BeautilfulSoup find_all method returns the same elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find-all-references

Hi here is my soup object:

```html
<td class="kategorie">
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">
  Herren
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc95f">
  Frauen
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc978">
  A-Jugend (U19)
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc98c">
  B-Jugend (U17)
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9a2">
  C-Jugend (U15)
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9b1">
  U17-Juniorinnen
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9b6">
  Futsal
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9bd">
  eSport
 </div>
</td>
```

How can I get all the c-codes and its corresponding text from the object?
For example: c-code: "c5ff5b1d0dc93c" and its corresponding text: "Herren" for the first row...

My code looks like this (categories is the soup object):

```
for category in categories.find_all('div'):
    category = categories.find('div')
    print(category)
```

I only receive the information of the first row....

```html
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**What happens?**

- `categories` holds your html
- in your loop you do `category = categories.find('div')` - `find('div')` always returns the first occurrence, so `category` will always be `<div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">Herren</div>`

You should do `category = element.get_text()` to get the text and `code = element.get('data-navi-cat')` to get the code.

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<td class="kategorie">
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc93c">
  Herren
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc95f">
  Frauen
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc978">
  A-Jugend (U19)
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc98c">
  B-Jugend (U17)
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9a2">
  C-Jugend (U15)
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9b1">
  U17-Juniorinnen
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9b6">
  Futsal
 </div>
 <div data-navi-cat="c5ff5b1d0dc9bd">
  eSport
 </div>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for element in soup.find_all('div'):
    category = element.get_text()
    code = element.get('data-navi-cat')
    print(category, code)
```

**Output**

```
  Herren
  c5ff5b1d0dc93c

  Frauen
  c5ff5b1d0dc95f

  A-Jugend (U19)
  c5ff5b1d0dc978

  B-Jugend (U17)
  c5ff5b1d0dc98c
```